# error invoking TomEEMicroProfileListener in REST app

Tags: tomcat, jax-rs

I started studying the REST API and noticed that when using a class marked with the @Path annotation, I get an error that does not affect the performance of the application in any way, but I still want to find out why this happens. I am using Tomee plume 9.1.0.

```java
@Path("/rs")
public class HelloWorld {
    @GET
    @Path("/sayHello")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello world";
    }
}
```

```
06-Jan-2024 04:36:46.537 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.openejb.observer.ObserverManager$MethodInvocation.invoke error invoking org.apache.tomee.microprofile.TomEEMicroProfileListener@2807bdeb
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: On a thread without an initialized context nor a classloader mapping a deployed app
        at org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.get(ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.java:366)
        at org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.getContext(ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.java:342)
        at org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.get(ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.java:377)
        at org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.get(ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.java:71)
        at org.apache.webbeans.config.WebBeansFinder.getSingletonInstance(WebBeansFinder.java:57)
        at org.apache.webbeans.config.WebBeansContext.getInstance(WebBeansContext.java:197)
        at org.apache.webbeans.config.WebBeansContext.currentInstance(WebBeansContext.java:215)
        at org.apache.webbeans.container.OwbCDI.getWebBeansContext(OwbCDI.java:47)
        at org.apache.webbeans.container.OwbCDI.instance(OwbCDI.java:52)
        at org.apache.webbeans.container.OwbCDI.select(OwbCDI.java:97)
        at io.smallrye.opentracing.SmallRyeTracingDynamicFeature.<init>(SmallRyeTracingDynamicFeature.java:30)
        at org.apache.tomee.microprofile.TomEEMicroProfileListener.registerMicroProfileJaxRsProviders(TomEEMicroProfileListener.java:150)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
        at org.apache.openejb.observer.ObserverManager$MethodInvocation.invoke(ObserverManager.java:402)
        at org.apache.openejb.observer.ObserverManager.doFire(ObserverManager.java:111)
        at org.apache.openejb.observer.ObserverManager.fireEvent(ObserverManager.java:100)
        at org.apache.openejb.loader.SystemInstance.fireEvent(SystemInstance.java:151)
        at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.configureFactory(CxfRsHttpListener.java:1328)
        at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication(CxfRsHttpListener.java:665)
        at org.apache.openejb.server.rest.RESTService.deployApplication(RESTService.java:546)
        at org.apache.openejb.server.rest.RESTService.afterApplicationCreated(RESTService.java:305)
        at org.apache.tomee.webservices.TomeeJaxRsService.afterApplicationCreated(TomeeJaxRsService.java:53)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
```

Comment: How did you configure the application?